# golang:alpine docker container on macOS throws "invalid symbol version for go.string" when importing gin-gonic/gin

Tags: macos, docker, go, alpine-linux

I am trying to run a very simple go/gin program on golang:alpine docker image.  This fails to run/build.

Run container:

```
docker run -it --rm golang:1.10.1-alpine sh
```

In the container paste:

```
apk update && apk add git gcc musl-dev

go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin

cat <<EOT > src/main.go
package main
import _ "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
func main() {
}
EOT

go run src/main.go
```

The error:

```
# command-line-arguments
2018/04/06 18:07:33 invalid symbol version for "go.string.\"aa87ca22be8b05378eb1c71ef320ad746e1d3b628ba79b9859f741e082542a3855\xdb\x0f\x849\x0e\x00\x00H\x8b[\bH\x83\xfb\x01\x0f\x8f\x17\r\x00\x00H\x8bH H\x85\xc9\x0f\x84\x01": -7
```

---

Host Machine: `macOS High Sierra 10.13.3, MacBook Pro Mid 2014, Intel i5`

Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:   18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:06:22 2018
 OS/Arch:   darwin/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  18.03.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   0520e24
  Built:    Wed Mar 21 23:14:32 2018
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

---

This works **without error on golang/stretch** image, though:

```
✗ dk run -it --rm golang:1.10.1-stretch bash                                        11:24AM
root@5d98f42504c2:/go# go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
root@5d98f42504c2:/go#
root@5d98f42504c2:/go# cat <<EOT > src/main.go
> package main
> import _ "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
> func main() {
> }
> EOT
root@5d98f42504c2:/go#
root@5d98f42504c2:/go# go run src/main.go
root@5d98f42504c2:/go#
```

---

What could be going wrong with alpine?  Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

**More Information**

Same error with CGO disabled.

This is a build time failure and with -x option fails at:

```
EOF
mkdir -p $WORK/b001/exe/
cd .
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link 
-o $WORK/b001/exe/a.out 
-importcfg $WORK/b001/importcfg.link 
-buildmode=exe 
-buildid=UZcMyOX9lILP9hahS-FF/kCN0nlKO7qaS5D1mwkHf/i8lsdHfkhJNsud-tI68Q/UZcMyOX9lILP9hahS-FF 
-extld=gcc /root/.cache/go-build/55/55d1e3d2979a75ff5a13bc75c855482f90c32615d3b9e9d42ed096051efec200-d
# command-line-arguments
2018/04/06 21:28:17 invalid symbol version for "go.string.\"aa87ca22be8b05378eb1c71ef320ad746e1d3b628ba79b9859f741e0
82542a3855\xdb\x0f\x849\x0e\x00\x00H\x8b[\bH\x83\xfb\x01\x0f
\x8f\x17\r\x00\x00H\x8bH H\x85\xc9\x0f\x84\x01": -7
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue. Have you tried building without CGO? Have you tried building with `-x` to see if it's a build time failure, and what command might have failed? Have you made sure you have the latest alpine image?

Comment: Without CGO fails with same error.  It's a build time failure.  Added output to description.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got resolved after I reset docker to factory defaults.

[image: Reset Docker]